# Error when pushing website content to gh-pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am an error when trying to push website content onto `gh-pages`:

```
git push using:  origin gh-pages
To https://github.com/harp29/cervini-bhatia-pc.git
 ! [rejected]        524585ce572db1fefbfb3a4b78c29ed721c92c47 -> gh-pages (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/harp29/cervini-bhatia-pc.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Here is the script from `package.json`:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server",
"dev": "webpack -d",
"prod": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
"clean": "rimraf ./dist/* ",
"deploy-gh": "npm run prod && git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh- 
pages"
```

What I have tried:

- `git pull` on both branches separately
- `git pull --rebase` on both

With `git pull --rebase` I get: `Already up-to-date`.
But running `npm run deploy-gh` I still get the same error

No luck... It was working fine before but I switched branches for some reason I'm not sure about and then this happened, now it doesn't "sync" it seems like.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: What about the error is unclear or disagreeable to you? Why didn't you post your `git status`? Why did you "switched branches for some reason I'm not sure about", and isn't that probably what you did wrong? It's most likely that you have rewritten history inadvertently or are otherwise trying to push to some incompatible branch. Since you probably shouldn't force-push, you need to show more context about what has changed, and `git status` is the place to start looking.

Comment: Yup tried - everything is up to date..

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Harpreets-MacBook-Pro:cervini-bhatia harpreetsingh$ git checkout gh-pages
Switched to branch 'gh-pages'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/gh-pages'.
Harpreets-MacBook-Pro:cervini-bhatia harpreetsingh$ git status
On branch gh-pages
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/gh-pages'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean